# CAT6 Actually Slowing down connection

Tags: networking, ethernet, home-networking, cat, cat6

I previously had cat5 from my router in the garage run through my house to my room. I then have that go into a gigabit switch, which goes to the computers throughout the room. Now that I have put in CAT6 into the room, I have been having problems, including one being that the connection was actually bottle-necked to 100mbps(when I checked via ethernet card status). I fixed this by just using a normal cat5 cable to the switch to my computer. Now the problem I face is that from the same location as my computer, my phone gets a faster speed on wifi than the ethernet itself. I have no idea why this would happen since cat6 should be considered a faster cable, right? If I wanted to fix this, would I just want to rerun from the wall port to the switch with cat5e cables?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I also have recently got a new router, which is the [ASUS RT-AC5300](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RT-AC5300/) along with the cable change in my room. If this may have effected it, please feel free to let me know:)

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that if you don't have all four cable pairs correctly connected, your 1000BASE-T (1 Gbps) connection will drop to 100BASE-TX (100 Mbps).

Another problem is that even experienced cable installers have trouble getting Category-6 or above to pass all the tests in the Category Test Suite.

Unless you have a real (read expensive) cable tester, you will not be able to certify a Category-6 cable. I don't mean any disrespect, but I seriously doubt that you could install a Category-6 cable and get it to pass the test suite.

Answer (score 1):

The cat6 cable you have is either damaged or badly terminated.

Cat6 cable is not necessarily faster, it is designed to work better with higher frequencies and noise cancellation - but has tighter requirements for how it can be run (bend radius, termination etc).

Both Cat5e and Cat6 can carry gigabit traffic (cat6e will do better on 10gig connections)

Comment: I have Cat5e run from my router through the walls and into my room. Would the mismatch between Cat5e and Cat6 possibly slow it down?

Comment: No, you can use cat6 patch cables on a cat5e cable or vise-versa.  Of-course, cable joins add reflections and worse depending on how they are done.   The key thing is to work out why your connection has negotiated at 100 megabit - this would probably not be a cable issue, unless wires are not broken.